# Apply a filter via button to match records

Tags: ms-access, filtering

I have a form with two subforms (3 tables, total).

Tables:
PI (patient information)
Referrals
Reports

The form displays PI at the top and then Referrals and Reports as subforms (see screenshot below)

[image]

In the current view, the form is displaying all referrals for patient #1 (1 referral available) and ALL reports regardless of whether it's tied to a referral or not. I'd like to create a button so that when clicked, it applies a filter to show ONLY reports that match the currently displayed ReferralID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [this page](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm) on how to refer to controls and properties on sub and parent forms. As for the button for applying the filter, this should be a  Toggle Button, clicked for applying the filter, or up, for removing it.

In your case, add to the Referrals sub Form a Toggle Button named *tbtnFilter*, and in the OnCurrent event of form, modify the Reports filter:

```
Me.Parent!Reports.Form.Filter = "ReferralsID = " & CStr(Me.ReferralsID)
Me.Parent!Reports.Form.FilterOn = Me.tbtnFilter
```

In the [tbtnFilter OnClick Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822512.aspx) apply and remove the filter, and modify the [ToggleButton.Caption Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196188.aspx) to be "Apply Filter" when up (FALSE), and "Remove Filter" When down (TRUE):

```
Me.Parent!Reports.Form.FilterOn = Me.tbtnFilter
Me.tbtnFilter.Caption = IIf(Me.tbtnFilter, "Remove", "Apply") & " Filter"
```

Comment: @Chris Ray have this answer? Iv'e edited the other answer too.

Comment: So, I inserted the code you put above into the On Click event of a command button. What it does: when the main form loads, the reports form is showing all reports. Then, when the button is clicked, it's showing only reports for that referral (YAY), but then, when navigating to another REFERRAL for the same patient, it's not automatically loading those reports, you have to click the command button again

Comment: @Chris Ray Yup, the code should run every time you navigate to another REFERRAL, the filter should be modified. The [event on record navigation is the OnCurrent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193159.aspx) event. It is a Form event.

Comment: @Chris Ray, I now added a Toggle Button to the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, Marlan. I'm going to take a look at this and give it another shot soon and will update you

Comment: Actually, you should (also?) apply the filter from _tbtnFilter_ OnClick event. Modifying answer

Comment: @ChrisRay, How was this answer?

Answer (score 0):

SubForm controls on PI Form have LinkChildFields property and LinkMasterFields property.

**Edit:**
You can have Reports form as a subform in Referrals sub form. Iv'e done it a few times, it runs nicely. It just may limit you a-bit in form design.

[MSDN Article on SubForm.LinkChildFields Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195880.aspx):

> You can use the LinkChildFields property (along with the
>   LinkMasterFields property) together to specify how Microsoft Access
>   links records in a form... to records in a subform... 
>   If these properties are set, Microsoft Access automatically updates the
>   related record in the subform when you change to a new record in a main form.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this doesn't give the option of seeing both linked and unlinked reports. It will only show me those reports that have a matching ReferralID

Comment: Sorry for this answer, Iv'e had trouble seeing the screenshot... I now have better understanding your question, I'm posting a new answer.